# Private key from Certificate generated with certreq is not exportable

Tags: certificate, private-key, certreq

I have created a Certificate with an inf-file and certreq with the following settings:

```
   $InfFile = @"
    [NewRequest]`r
    FriendlyName = $FQDN
    Subject = "CN=$FQDN,OU=$OrganizationalUnit,O=$Organisation,L=$Locality,S=$State,C=$CountryName,E=$Email"`r
    KeySpec = 1
    KeyLength = 2048
    Exportable = TRUE`r
    RequestType = PKCS10`r

    [Extensions]
    2.5.29.17 = "{text}"
    _continue_ = "DNS=$FQDN&"
    _continue_ = "DNS=$SERVERNAME"
"@
```

If I run this in a Script, the certificate will be created. But I'm unable to export the private key even though I set the value of "Exportable" to true. It seems no key is associated with the certificate as shown in this picture:

[Certificate without key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo8c4.png)

Here a Certificate with associated Key for reference:

[Certificate with Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad52j.png)

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, any ideas?

Cheers
Buffalosoldier

Comment: Just found the answer to my own question. I had to add the following to the inf file:
MachineKeySet = TRUE

Comment: You can write that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer to my own question. I had to add the following to the inf file: MachineKeySet = TRUE